# Transposing dataframe and sorting

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like so (the data represents a matrix):

```
           Arnston    Berg    Carlson
Arnston    0.00       1.00    2.00
Berg       1.00       0.00    3.00
Carlson    2.00       3.00    0.00
```

and I want to transpose it so that the row and column names are linked, and their associated value is displayed as a new column with it sorted from smallest to largest.  I only need to keep one of the row-column combinations because they are always the same (e.g. Arnston, Berg == 1.00 and Berg, Arnston ==  1.00)

My desired output is:

```
Arnston, Arnston   0.00
Berg, Berg         0.00
Carlson, Carlson   0.00
Arnston, Berg      1.00
Arnston, Carlson   2.00
Berg, Carlson      3.00
```

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pandas [melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) function is awesome.

In:

```
df = df.reset_index() #Make your index into a column
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars = ['index']) #Reshape data
df = df[df['index'] <= df['variable']].sort_values(by = 'value') #Remove duplicates, sort
df ['col'] = df['index'] +','+ df['variable'] #Concatenate strings
df = df[['col','value']] #Remove unnecessary columns
df = df.set_index('col') #Set strings to index
df
```

Out:

```
                value
col 
Arnston,Arnston 0
Berg,Berg       0
Carlson,Carlson 0
Arnston,Berg    1
Arnston,Carlson 2
Berg,Carlson    3
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your matrix is symmetric, so you can build up an index list and value list of the upper diagonal matrix using a nested loop.  The second loop, however, should start at the inner loop's value.

```
vals = []
idx = []
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(i, df.shape[1]):
        idx.append((df.index[i], df.columns[j]))
        vals.append(df.iat[i, j])
>>> pd.Series(vals, index=idx)
(Arnston, Arnston)    0
(Arnston, Berg)       1
(Arnston, Carlson)    2
(Berg, Berg)          0
(Berg, Carlson)       3
(Carlson, Carlson)    0
dtype: float64
```

To give some timing comparisons:

```
dfc = df.copy()

# Nested loop.
%%timeit
vals = []
idx = []
for i in range(dfc.shape[0]):
    for j in range(i, dfc.shape[1]):
        idx.append((dfc.index[i], dfc.columns[j]))
        vals.append(dfc.iat[i, j])
pd.Series(vals, index=idx)
1000 loops, best of 3: 187 µs per loop

# Melt.
%%timeit
df = dfc.reset_index()
df = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['index'])
df = df[df['index']<=df['variable']].sort_values(by='value')
df ['col'] = df['index'] +','+ df['variable']
df = df[['col','value']]
df = df.set_index('col')
100 loops, best of 3: 3.39 ms per loop
```

The timing is reversed for a larger 100x100 symmetrical matrix, where `melt` melts the competition:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 100))
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    df.iat[i, i] = 1
    for j in range(i + 1, df.shape[1]):
        df.iat[i, j] = df.iat[j, i]
df.columns = df.index = ['col_' + str(i) for i in range(100)]
dfc = df.copy()

# nested loop:
10 loops, best of 3: 55.2 ms per loop

# melt:
100 loops, best of 3: 5.72 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that uses `numpy`:

```
%%timeit
df = pd.DataFrame([['Arnston', 0.0, 1.0, 2.0],
               ['Berg', 1.0, 0.0, 3.0],
               ['Carlson', 2.0, 3.0, 0.0]],
                columns=['Name','Arnston','Berg','Carlson'])

df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)

upper = np.triu_indices_from(df.as_matrix())  #indices from upper tri
vals = df.as_matrix()[upper] #vals at upper inds
idx = [(df.index[i], df.columns[j]) for i,j in zip(upper[0],upper[1])]

# w/ numpy
1000 loops, best of 3: 810 µs per loop
```

Results:

```
In [11]: pd.Series(vals, index=idx)
Out[11]:    
        (Arnston, Arnston)    0
        (Arnston, Berg)       1
        (Arnston, Carlson)    2
        (Berg, Berg)          0
        (Berg, Carlson)       3
        (Carlson, Carlson)    0
        dtype: float64
```

When you run it on Alexander's larger `dfc`:

```
%%timeit
upper = np.triu_indices_from(dfc.as_matrix())  #indices from upper tri
vals = dfc.as_matrix()[upper] #vals at upper inds
idx = [(dfc.index[i], dfc.columns[j]) for i,j in zip(upper[0],upper[1])]

100 loops, best of 3: 15.3 ms per loop
```

not quite as fast as `melt`.